# Lua calling nested function form string

Tags: lua

How to call a nested function from string?

```
function first()
    function nested() print('function: nested') end
    print('function: first')
end

_G["first"]() --Calls first function from string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nested` is a global variable, so you can call it with `nested()` or `_G.nested()` or `_G["nested"]()`.

Comment: thx, but that's not working for me. It throws "attempt to call a nil value (field 'nested')"

Comment: `nested` is only defined after `first` is called.